# Error calling FIONREAD under ioctl() function in Cygwin

Tags: c++, unix, serial-port, cygwin, unistd.h

I have called the method `ioctl` to check the number of bytes available with the following code :

```
::ioctl(serial_port, FIONREAD, &available);
```

I'm compiling this from Cygwin under windows 10. But I get this error:
`error: ‘FIONREAD’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘FREAD’?`

How can I fix this? I want to check if there're bytes in the input buffer so when I poll, I don't get errors when it's empty. I have been having `input/output error with error no.5`.

if it's not possible to find the FIONREAD constant, is there another way to avoid the `input/output error`? I am using blocking mode too with `VMIN = 0 and VTIME = 1`. So it's waiting about `100ms` with every read.

Those are my include files :

```
#include <string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include <fcntl.h> 

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <errno.h> 
#include <termios.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `sys/socket.h`

my `prova.c` test code

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{

int bytesAv =0 ;
int m_Socket=4 ;
if ( ioctl (m_Socket,FIONREAD,&bytesAv) < 0 )
{
    // Error
}
}
```

the compiler does not show any error

```
$ gcc -c prova.c -Wall
```